# How to use conditions on functions like strpos() in PHP?

Tags: php, string, strpos

I wanted to check if a string contains specific words? According [How do I check if a string contains a specific word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word) I can use `strpos()` function.

**Sample Code I wrote**

```
if(strpos($value, 'filters(10)') === false){
    //Do something
} else {
    //Do Another Thing
}
```

If I need to check specific word `filters(10)` above functions works fine. **But I need to check all numbers above 10** with filter word.

**Example**

```
$value = 'bla bla  bla bla' // Should return false
$value = 'bla bla filters(1) bla bla' // Should return false
$value = 'bla bla filters(5) bla bla' // Should return false
$value = 'bla bla filters(10) bla bla' // Should return true
$value = 'bla bla filters(15) bla bla' // Should return true
$value = 'bla bla filters(20) bla bla' // Should return true
```

How to modify my code to get above results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use `Regex` for getting that particular no. and then apply further conditions.

**Regex:** `filters\((\d+)\)`

This will match `filters(` and then capture digits and then `)`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/870750)

```
preg_match("#filters\((\d+)\)#", $value, $matches);
if(isset($matches[1]) && $matches[1]>10)
{
    //do something on true
}
else
{
    //do something on false
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly fine. Even I read lots of article about preg_match still I can't impliment something like what you have written my self... Can you provide a link to which explain how to write preg_match easily... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the element in `filters()` and compare it with 10.

```
if(($pos = strpos($value, 'filters(10)')) === false){
    if(intval(substr($value, $pos + strlen('filters('))) > 10) {
    //Do something
    } else {// do another thing}
} else {
    //Do Another Thing
}
```